# How to allow line breaks before the numbers in paragraph enumerations in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, enumerate, context-mkiv

I have some enumerated items, in paragraph form, like this:

```
\setuppapersize[A5]
\showgrid

\setupitemize[text, r]

\starttext
    \startcolumns[n=2]
        \startitemize
            \item This is a sentence.
            \item This is another sentence.
            \item This is yet another sentence.
            \item This sentences comes after the one before.
        \stopitemize
    \stopcolumns
\stoptext
```

This should make two distinct columns, however, text from the left column ends up running long and overlapping the second column.

ConTeXt does not appear to allow a break to appear before an `\item` or between an `\item` and the first word following immediately after the `\item`, so I often find content is pushed into the neighboring column, e.g.:

```
                                  |
(i.) This is some text. (ii.) This|
is some more text. (iii.) This is |
yet some more text in a sentence. (iv.) This
is the last sentence.             |
```

How can I allow breaks to appear before `\item`, so that the text will not flow into the neighboring column? E.g.:

```
                                  |
(i.) This is some text. (ii.) This|
is some more text. (iii.) This is |
yet some more text in a sentence. |
(iv.) This is the last sentence.  |
```

Comment: Adding `\setuptolerance[horizontal,stretch]` will show you that there actually is a breakpoint before the items. (Or replace the text of the first item with “This is the sentence” to see it appear without the emergency stretch.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I already stated in my comment, there already is a valid breakpoint and TeX does consider it during line break. If you would like, below example shows you a (very hackish) way to adjust the penalty at this point without having to modifiy `strc-itm.mkvi`.

The other point, allowing a break *after* an item marker is inserted, is a bit more complicated. Thus I defined a macro that reverts a sequence of non-breaking elements that will have been inserted at this point, and assigned it to the `command` parameter. This would be the brute force solution short of defining your own item commands (which is the solution I would prefer).

Here you go:

```
\setuppapersize[A5]
\showgrid

\unprotect

%% This undos a sequence of spaces made by \strc_itemgroups_start_item
\def\correct_penalty{%
  \ifnum\lastnodetype=\penaltynodecode
    \unpenalty
    \removeunwantedspaces
    \unpenalty
    \removehboxes
    \unpenalty
    \removehboxes
    \removeunwantedspaces
    \space
    \penalty0
  \fi%
}

\defineitemgroup[myitemize]
\setupitemgroup [myitemize][
  lefttext=(, righttext=),
  symbol=r,   option=text,
  %% <hacks>
  command=\correct_penalty,   %% allow a break after the symbol
  textdistance=1em\penalty-42,%% There already *is* a breakpoint
                              %% before the item; adjust its penalty
                              %% here.
  %% </hacks>
]

\protect

\starttext
  \startcolumns[n=2]
    % \setuptolerance[horizontal,stretch] %% turn this on for less hassle
    \startmyitemize
      \item This is a sentence.
      \item This is another sentence.
      \item This is yet another nice sentence.
      \item This sentences comes after the one before.
    \stopmyitemize
  \stopcolumns
\stoptext
```

The result is rather ugly: you traded overfull boxes by underfull ones.
[image: modified in-text itemization]